# Databinding works for string but won't work for string inside an object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

So I have a String property bound to the Text property of a Textbox and it works fine -

```
public String MyString { get; set; }
MyString = "Hello World";
```

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyString}"....
```

However when I try to bind using a string inside an object it doesn't work...like so

```
public class MyObject
{
    public String MyString { get; set; }
}

MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.MyString = "Hello World";
```

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=myObject.MyString}"...
```

I cannot understand why this isn't binding. All I have done is put the string inside a class and then changed the xaml to reflect that. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Check the output window for BindingExpression errors and post them here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose the myObject instance with a property on your ViewModel, instead of just using a local variable (which you appear to be doing based on the code you posted). Something like this:

```
public MyObject Obj { get; set; }

Obj = new MyObject()  { MyString = "Hello World" };
```

and in your XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Obj.MyString}" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be making the changes after the binding takes place and since you do not appear to [implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) there are no updates to the binding once the string/object is set.

*(You might also want to have a look at [the overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) if you are not that familiar with bindings.)*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John. You should be using INotifyPropertyChanged or a Dependency Property to properly bind the property to your UI. It's very possible that the binding is working, but appears as an empty string because the bind occurred before the value was set.

When do you set your DataContext?